# No video output on PS3, and cannot 'reset' output

Tags: ps3, technical-issues

When I plug in the Component or Composite video cables and turn on my PS3, I can hear the startup sound but there's no video output.

I've tried to do the video reset multiple times (Put the system in standby, hold down the power button, then in 5 seconds you get a beep. However, when I hold down the button there's never a beep within 5 seconds. If I hold it down for about a minute the PS3 then shuts off.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Does the HDMI work?

Comment: Nope.  There's no audio either.  With the AV cables I at least hear the symphony sound.

Answer (score 1):

hold down the power on button for about a minute when you turn the machine on(keep your finger on it).  This always did reset my old fatboy or put it into safe mode but the firmawre revisions might have made this harder since this kept getting used by device hackers.

Comment: A few months ago, holding the button while the PS3 (fatboy) is booting was still the leading solution for resetting video settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before, but for one reason alone. If you bring your PS3 or use it somewhere and use an hdmi cable and set it in the settings for the output of the video and audio it will not reconfigure automatically to the composite or component output. To solve this you need to plug it back into a TV with HDMI and reconfigure it to the composite or component output. You might not need the HDMI cable if you get good enough or look up the mapping to do it without the video. Hope this helps.